# How to stream videos from any url in android application?

Tags: android, youtube, video-streaming, vimeo

I want to use media player to play videos from any url. I found that, youtube video can be played using rtsp url, but no other videos, like vimeo video, can be played in app. Is there any method to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Vimeo doesn't provide support for RTSP, you could use flash to this end since Android support flash, and can be easily add with a WebView and simple HTML

Also, please keep in mind that playing Vimeo videos through a non-Vimeo player usually constitutes a violation of their TOS.